# Is there a book title generator that takes an input and outputs plausible titles with related words?

Tags: software, tools, titles

There are a couple book title generators out there (Google will find them for you). Unfortunately, none of them seem to take any *input*. That is, they all generate titles by assembling words from a database, and the user cannot influence which words are chosen and how they are assembled. What I want to do is input a word, like "Sword" and be given a bunch of *plausible* titles that contain this word or related words (like "knight" or "knife") and that are not utter nonsense (like "Sword Cake").

Does such a title (or phrase) generator exist?

Comment: It might not be quite your answer but there are a ton of name generators at Seventh Santctum. http://www.seventhsanctum.com/index-name.php

Comment: Hmm. If you know what your book is about, wouldn't it be easier to make up a title that describes it than to get a bunch of randomly-generated titles and try to pick one that matches your book? If your creative enough to write a book, aren't you creative enough to make up a title for it? If you're stuck on one word, like your first idea for a title uses the same word twice and you need a synonym, then you could look up synonyms for that one word.

Comment: @Jay I don't need a title for a book I have written.

Comment: Okay, so just curious now: What do you need a book title for? What, do you need a title for a fictitious book citation somewhere, that sort of thing?

Comment: @Jay I want titles as a writing prompt.

Comment: I want to read the novel *Sword Cake*.

Comment: There used to be a custom that when a military officer gets married, the officer's dress sword is used to cut the wedding cake. That could be A basis for a novel called *Sword Cake*. Perhaps someone will write it and pay me for the idea (LOL)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the gist of what your book is, which you should,  try http://www.nameboy.com/

Designed for domain names, it will give a big list of synonyms and all the possible combinations.

So if you enter Sword and Warrior, you'll get lots of variations. Knife Fighter, Sword Soldier, etc.

Yes, a lot of it will be nonsense, but it should help get the juices going.

Comment: Sounds nice, but all I ever get is:"We're sorry, your search seems to have expired."

Comment: Bummer. Another one I like is http://www.domainsbot.com/

Answer (score 3):

I was just now looking for the same thing and came across this tool that worked for me: http://www.adazing.com/book-title-generator/

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any software to recommend, but I do have some tips.
If you know the main idea of your story, main protagonists name, and setting, you can find a great name using those little things.
If that doesn't work, give something slightly doesn't seem to fit at first, but starts to make more and more sense as the story progresses. 
Or you could find my quotev account (Bracelet girls) and I could pretend to be a software.